# Function to check a variable and change it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a calculator to turn RGB values into Hexidecimal numbers. as I was coding I realised I had written the same code three times to check user input for red, green, and blue. So I thought, why not use a function to check my variables for me!! Here is my code:

```
invalid_msg = 'Whoops looks like you have entered incorrect information'
def check_rgb(var):
    while var > 255 or var < 0:
        print invalid_msg
        var = int(raw_input('Please enter a value between 0 and 255:'))
    return var

def rgb_hex():
    red = int(raw_input('Enter your value for red.'))
    check_rgb(red)
    green = int(raw_input('Enter your value for green.'))
    while green > 255 or red < 0:
        print invalid_msg
        green = int(raw_input('Enter your value for green.'))
    blue = int(raw_input('Enter your value for blue.'))
    while blue > 255 or red < 0:
        print invalid_msg
        blue = int(raw_input('Enter your value for blue.'))
    val = (red << 16) + (green << 8) + blue
    print '%s' % (hex(val)[2:]).upper()

rgb_hex()
```

The issue is with redeclaring the variable. Right now this stores the value entered into the function to the variable 'var' not red.

Comment: Paste the code in the question, not in an iframe to pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Davis Yoshida mentions, merely doing `check_rgb(red)` doesn't change the original value of `red`, since you forgot to save the value that `check_rgb` returns.

I recommend expanding your helper function so that it gets the user input and validates it too. Here's an example that also makes sure that the input is a valid integer in the proper range. This code also shows an easier way to print the hex representation of the RGB value.

```
def get_color_byte(name):
    while True:
        s = raw_input('Enter a value from 0 to 255 for %s: ' % name)
        try:
            v = int(s)
            if not 0 <= v <= 255:
                raise ValueError('Out of range')
            return v
        except ValueError as e:
            print e

r, g, b = [get_color_byte(name) for name in ('red', 'green', 'blue')]
rgb = (r << 16) | (g << 8 ) | b
print '%06X' % rgb
```

**test**

```
Enter a value from 0 to 255 for red: hello
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
Enter a value from 0 to 255 for red: 12.5
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12.5'
Enter a value from 0 to 255 for red: -5
Out of range
Enter a value from 0 to 255 for red: 300
Out of range
Enter a value from 0 to 255 for red: 240
Enter a value from 0 to 255 for green: 13
Enter a value from 0 to 255 for blue: 7
F00D07
```

As an alternative to `print '%06X' % rgb` you could use the more modern `format` function:

```
print format(rgb, '06X')
```

In both of those, the capital `X` says to use capital letters in the hex string.

Comment: This is pretty brilliant, But why did you not include the call for int in the variable definition s?

Comment: Oh I see! If the user enters something that cannot be converted into an integer, there will be an error. So redefining the variable in try: allows us to except the error! ... why not move the whole var declaration to inside the try statement?

Comment: @Joe The general rule is to minimize the code that goes inside a `try` block. That way, you only catch the errors that you want to catch, and know how to handle. If other unexpected errors occur, that usually indicates a problem in the program logic, and when that happens you want the program to fail noisily and print an error traceback to give you information that will help you fix the code.

Comment: @Joe (cont) In this particular case, the built-in `raw_input` function will never raise an exception, unless the user interrupts the program (eg, with Ctrl-C). If that happens, we don't want to pester the user for more input, we want the program to terminate, but if you want you can catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception so you can do stuff before exiting, eg print a "goodbye" message.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like something like

```
red = check_rgb(red)
```

When you just do

```
check_rgb(red)
```

The return value is not used.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the condition on the three colors calling separately the function and then compare all them in the same statement:

```
red_ok = check_rgb(red)
green_ok = check_rgb(green)
blue_ok = check_rgb(blue)
if (red_ok and green_ok and blue_ok) :
    val = (red << 16) + (green << 8) + blue
    print '%s' % (hex(val)[2:]).upper()
```